# Using readline() in r+ mode affects write()

Tags: python, file, readline

I ran this code:

```
fh = open('text.txt','r+')
fh.write('Line0\n')
fh.readlines()
fh.close()
```

Before running the code, `text.txt` contained:

```
Line1
Line2
```

After I ran the code `text.txt` contained:

```
Line1
Line2
Line0
```

I thought the `r+` mode positions the cursor in the beginning of the text, therefore I would expect this output:

```
Line0
Line2
```

How can you explain `Line0` being appended to the end of the file?

If I remove `fh.readlines()` from the code, I get the expected output. How comes `fh.readlines()` affects backwards?

Comment: Throw in a `fh.flush()` before the `fh.readlines()`. It depends when it it pushed to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python opens text files [with internal buffering](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open). The write `fh.write('Line0\n')` my be stored in the buffer before the read `fh.readlines()` is executed. You can suppress buffering by opening the file with a single-byte buffer:

```
fh = open('text.txt','r+',buffering=1)
```

However, this will significantly slow down your application.